# Editing other elements of page with jquery accordion- active & default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this basic accordion.

```
 $('#accordion').accordion({ 
    collapsible: true, 
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
 });
```

I would like to affect other elements (h3's, p's, etc.) on the page (specifically, those below the accordion) as the accordion is opened (state: active) and closed (state: default).

I already know how to edit the accordion's headings and content itself when it's state changes but I don't understand how to affect outside elements that aren't a part of the accordion, on the page. How do I do this?

HTML basic style is this repeated thrice:

```
<div>
     <h3>Heading</h3>
     <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us clearer example, like providing the HTML structure and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

**Tested**

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
     collapsible: true, 
     active: false,
     heightStyle: "content",
     activate: function( event, ui ) {
         console.log(ui.newHeader.prop("id"));
     }
});
```

**Note:** CURRENTLY, If you open another header it will output the id of the opened header, however if you closed the opened header then it would return `undefined` which you can use for future checking.. For more info click [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)..

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJy5C/)..

Comment: Hey I tried this method but there was no change. I put $('#skills').css('background','blue'); to check if it would change this div but it didn't.

Comment: It worked! But it has a bug- when I close the open header it just executes the function inside activate again. I already tried removing active: false from the code but to no effect.

Comment: That's not a bug, it's explained in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate).. That's why I told you if you don't want to do anything if you select the **SAME** header then use `if(ui.newHeader.prop("id") != undefined)` as your condition..

Comment: Okay I got it. My apologies for not realizing! Is there any shortcut way to restore whatever changes I made inside the if statement to default?

Comment: I don't think so, you have to revert everything manually, I guess.. BTW, try changing it yourself then if there is a prob then create a new question..  I think I already answered your main question.. ^^

Comment: Okay I'll do it manually! Yes, you did answer the question! Thank you so much!